# Pandas sort all rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Is there a way to sort each row of a pandas data frame?

I don't care about columns names or row indexes, I just want a table with the values of each row sorted from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.sort` with `axis=1` on the numpy data:

```
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, (2,4)))

# output
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1)[:,::-1], 
             index=df.index, 
             columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  9  6  6  1
1  8  7  2  1
```

If you want to override your original dataframe:

```
df[:] = np.sort(df.values, axis=1)[:,::-1]
```

### Update

`np.sort(df)[:,::-1]` works as well, `df` is downcast to a numpy array, and `axis=-1` is default.